# Find $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|z|=2i(\bar{z}+1)$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, complex-numbers

I was trying to solve the following problem:

> Find $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $$|z|=2i(\bar{z}+1).$$

I tried to solve the problem by letting $z=x+iy$ and found out that the solutions are $z=-1+i\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},-1-i\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$. But as tried to justify the solutions $z=-1-i\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ does not satisfy the equation.

I couldn't find any error in my calculation. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without showing us your calculation, no one can help you.

Answer (score 3):

Let $z=a+bi$, where $\{a,b\}\subset\mathbb R$.

Thus,
$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=2i(a-bi+1),$$
which gives $a+1=0$ and $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=2b$.

Hence, $\sqrt{b^2+1}=2b$ and since $b>0$, we get the answer:
$$\left\{-1+\frac{1}{\sqrt3}i\right\}$$

Answer (score 2):

Rewriting the equation:

$$|z|=2i(\bar{z}+1) \;\;\iff\;\; \bar{z} = \frac{|z|}{2i} - 1 = - 1 -i \frac{|z|}{2}\,$$

Taking conjugates on both sides:

$$
z = - 1 + i \,\frac{|z|}{2} \tag{1}
$$

Multiplying the two:

$$
|z|^2= \left( - 1-i \frac{|z|}{2}\right) \left( - 1 + i \frac{|z|}{2}\right) = (-1)^2 - \left(i \frac{|z|}{2}\right)^2 = 1 + \frac{|z|^2}{4} \;\iff\; |z|^2 = 4/3
$$

Substituting back in $(1)\,$:

$$
z = - 1 +  i \frac{|z|}{2} = -1 + i \,\frac{1}{2} \,\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}} = -1 + i \, \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The equation you should get is

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = 2i(x-iy + 1)\\
\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = y + 2(x+1)i$$

which means that

1. $2y=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$
2. $2(x+1)=0$

From the second equation, you get $x=-1$, and the first equation becomes

$$2y=\sqrt{y^2+1}$$

Now, you **SQUARE** the equation and get $$4y^2=y^2+1$$

and get $$y^2=\frac{1}{3}$$

---

Now, the equation $y^2=\frac13$ has **two** solutions, but since you got that equation by **squaring** some other equation, you should know that some of the solutions of the second equation may not solve the first equation. In your case, $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ solves the equation, because $$2\cdot \frac1{\sqrt{3}}=\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2+1}$$

but $y=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ does not solve the equation, because $$2\cdot\left(- \frac1{\sqrt{3}}\right)\neq 2\cdot\frac1{\sqrt{3}}=\sqrt{\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Here I think is your mistake: from $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=2i(x-yi+1)$ you get $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=2y$ therefore $y \ge 0$. So after finding out $x, y$ you must filter out the solutions that doesn't satisfy $y \ge 0$

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution by a different means... Let $z=re^{i\theta}$. Then

$$
\begin{align}
|z|
&=r=2i(re^{-i\theta}+1)\\
&=2i(r\cos\theta-i\sin\theta+1)
\end{align}
$$

From the real and imaginary parts we have

$$
0=r\cos\theta+1\\
r=2r\sin\theta
$$

From the second equation we get $\theta=\pi/6$ or $\theta=5\pi/6$. However, we must choose $\theta=-5\pi/6$ to assure that $r$ is positive. Thus,

$$r=-\frac{1}{\cos\theta}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$$

and finally,

$$
\begin{align}
z
&=re^{i\theta}\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}e^{i5\pi/3}}\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\left(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)\\
&=-1+\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}
\end{align}
$$

in agreement with the other solutions.